# How to iterate objects in json whit jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am returning one JSON response from the server:

```
{'error':'true',fields:[[{'pk':2,'title':'test'}],{'votes':20,'cant':{1:0,2:3}}]}
Console Dev return
Object { error="true", fields=[2]}
```

I'm trying to get all the data fields[2], but not work, I'm doing something:

```
$.each(data.fields, function(i,item){
    console.log(data.fields[i]);
})
```

**Question:** I know that I'm doing wrong, I want to access all the data in the order fields[2], pk and title.

Thanks.

Comment: not data.fields[i] its item.fields[i]

Comment: is this your full JSON? it seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch fields[2] using following:

```
$(data.fields).last()[0] // Give {votes: 20, cant: Object}
```

which you can use to iterate and get all data as:

```
var other_data = $(data.fields).last()[0]
$.each(other_data, function(key, value){
  console.log('key : ' + key + '  value: ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is need some corrections try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/dy5Kk/1/)

```
$.each(data.fields[1], function(i,item){
    console.log(item);
})
```